# Querying data remotely using New Relic API throwing "404 error"

Tags: api, xmlhttprequest, newrelic

Im using the following AJAX request to send request to New Relic, however its always throws "404 Not Found" error.

Following is the code:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", "https://insights-api.newrelic.com/v1/accounts/REMAINING.URL", true);
client.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
client.setRequestHeader("X-Query-Key", "QUERY.KEY");
client.send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the origin of the XMLHttpRequest (XHR) or Ajax is different to the requested API's URL, Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) prevents from accessing the API. Hence, this doesn't work. To implement this, the API will have to be requested by the back-end via .NET, JAVA, PHP, Python, etc. any server side technology and the result will have to be sent to the client Ajax calls.